# how to populate a form field using a different form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app i have two models `Shops` and `Products`, Products belongs to Shop, and Shop has many Products. What i want to accomplish here is that when a user creates a new shop they add a `state field`, there is this same `state field` in Product form too, i would like to fill the product `State field` automatically using the value of the shop `State field`.

I have tried using the value of option of the text_field tag what i did in my product form is

```
<%= form.text_field :state, value: @current_shop.state %>
```

but it does not work it gives this error:
undefined method `state' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Please post the html of your full form, also your file name

Answer (score 0):

`@current_shop` is nil so you are getting this error. Make sure the instance variable is set properly in the controller.

Comment: could you post the form and the controller create action and permitted params